# Trying to printing vector values throught double pointer variable that is a pointer to a vector created inside a function in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, vector, printing

I'm with a situation similar to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void madeVector(int **occurr){
    int vector[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int *pOccurr;

    pOccurr = vector;
    occurr = &pOccurr;

    printf("\n--==[Inside Function]==--\n\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf(" %i", *(*occurr + i));
    }

    printf("\n\n");
}

int main()
{
    int **pp;

    madeVector(pp);

    printf("\n--==[Outside Function]==--\n\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf(" %i", *(pp + i));
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I need to print all number in vector inside function "madeVector" and "main" using double pointer variables, how showed in code. But, it works only inside function "madeVector". I don't know how to print in "main" function. I tryed everthing, but it doesn't work.

Would someone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem: you don't allocate memory to store data anywhere. `vector` is local to the function.

Comment: ... and so is `pOccurr`.

Comment: Added 2 more canonical dupes to the list. The last one is probably the best for this case.

Comment: It's almost working.

Comment: '#define TAM 5

void madeVector(int **occurr){
    int *vector = malloc(sizeof(int) * TAM);
    int *pOccurr;

    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
        vector[i] = i + 1;

    pOccurr = vector;
    occurr = &pOccurr;

    printf("\n-[Inside Function]-\n\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
        printf(" %i", *(*occurr + i));
    }

    printf("\n\n");
}

int main()
{
    int **pp;

    madeVector(pp);

    printf("\n-[Outside Function]-\n\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
        printf(" %i", (*pp + i));
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}

Comment: But, vector inside function "madeVector" prints: **1 2 3 4 5** - perfect!
However, inside function "main" it prints: **1 5 9 13 17** - And I don't know why it happens!

Comment: Until now I don't find a solution for my problem. If I find it, I'll write here. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I solved this problem!

Comment: #define TAM 5

void madeVector(int **occurr){
    int *vector = malloc(sizeof(int) * TAM);
    int *pOccurr;

    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
        vector[i] = i + 1;

    pOccurr = vector;
    occurr = &pOccurr;

    printf("\nInside\n\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
        printf(" %d", *(*occurr + i));
    }

    printf("\n\n");
}

int main()
{
    int *q;
    int **pp;

    q = &*pp;

    madeVector(pp);

    printf("\nOutside\n\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
        printf(" %d", (*q + i));
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}